# How to make a javascript script file private?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

I want to know how to make it so that users the visit my website can't see a javascript script file.

Let me elaborate:

Sometimes, in my Javascript, I have some config information for stuff like Firebase that I don't want others to see. If someone has that information, they could potentially take it and run it on their localhost and mess with my data. I need to have the private config information on my websites Javascript, or else the site won't work. But if others see that script, then they can copy it and use it on their site, which will mess up everything. I want to know how to make a private script.

If that's not possible, that's fine. I just want to know what I should do then.

Here are some things I have tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    // config information
  </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

But that doesn't work. With Inspect Element, a user can easily find it.

Another idea was this:

```
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
```

But that doesn't help either, user can just inspect element, then right click on the link and say "Reveal Script in Source Panel"

What should I do?

If it's not possible to make the script private, just tell me. I just want to know what I should do.

Comment: if a browser needs a file, then a user can read the file - you'll need to start from scratch

Comment: @JaromandaX What do you mean?

Comment: You absolutely do NOT want to do that. Find another way...Perhaps serve your `index.html` with an ExpressJS app and expose an endpoint such as `/config` or `/authenticate` and do the authentication on the server side, then return the result as JSON. Then, on the client side, you can use the result without having exposes configuration details.

Comment: I mean, if the browser needs the file, then the owner of the browser can read the file ... thought that was obvious

Comment: Nonononono, I'm saying people who visit my site @JaromandaX

Comment: yes, I know exactly what you are saying ... you don't understand what I'm saying

Comment: @JaromandaX this isn't just for firebase, it's for others too

Comment: @JabariDash Good idea, can you maybe make an answer with a little more detail? I think I understand your idea, but I'm not sure I'm right

Comment: I'm not even talking about firebase ... in general, you can't send something to a browser that is hidden from the user

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay that was my question, I'm asking if it's possible to send something to a browser hidden from the user. According to @ Jabori Dash it is possible.

Comment: As @JaromandaX said, if the user owns the browser, the user can see the file. That is why they are the "client." I'll give you an analogy. Your website is a restaurant, you are the server, and the person opening your site is the client. Only the server (the chef) knows the secret recipe (config files) that are used to prepare a dish (webpage). You then "serve" the dish to the client. You don't put your secret recipe on the client's plate (client side code) because it's their food to eat.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thanks, that makes sense @JabariDash

Comment: You obviously don't understand what Jabari Dash suggested if you think he said that!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX yes i understood wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All client resources like HTML, CSS, JS, images and other files should be public. You can hide the file by adding an entry to .htaccess, for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \config.js$ - [R=404]
```

but in my opinion it does not make sense, this file is probably needed to run your application. All files served to client applications are public. Don't keep sensitive data in JS files, you can keep sensitive informations in configuration files on the backend siede but you can't share them with the client side application.

Comment: Will accept your answer but it says to wait 3 minutes

Comment: Happy to help. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Hi looks like you need to call firebase api. But don't do this in javascript from client side you should never render sensitive info to client side. Do a call on server side on post back from client instead.